# Is it possible to wget / curl protected files from GCS?

Tags: google-cloud-storage

Is it possible to wget / curl protected files from Google Cloud Storage without making them public? I don't mind a fixed predefined token. I just want to avoid the case where my public file gets leeched, costing me good dollars.

Comment: what research have you already done which might make you believe that it is/isn't

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Another way, if as you say you don't mind getting a token externally, is to use curl to set the 'Authorization' header in your call to GCS like so:

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer 1/fFBGRNJru1FQd44AzqT3Zg" https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/bucket/o/object?alt=media
```

The 'alt=media' query string parameter is necessary to download the object data directly instead of receiving a JSON response.

You can copy and paste the token obtained by authorizing with the Cloud Storage JSON API separately in the [OAuth 2.0 Playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/).

See also:
https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control
https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/get

Comment: how to generate token for Service Account: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/create-enable-service-accounts-for-instances#applications

Comment: Even easier way to generate the token: run `gcloud auth print-access-token | head -1`

Answer (score 6):

You can use [Signed URLs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control#Signed-URLs). This allows you to create a signed URL that can be used to download an object without additional authentication.

Answer (score 3):

You could also use the [curlwget chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/curlwget/jmocjfidanebdlinpbcdkcmgdifblncg?hl=en) so whenever you download something on Chrome it will create the url with headers etc to allow you to `wget` your file.